# object cannot be cast from DBNULL to other types model mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a web app with mvc5 i have multiple users in my database
for eg

USERS

user1) username=ibrahim Password=1ibrahim
user2) username=admin password=4321

when i am logging in from user 1(ibrahim) the page is successfully redirecting to welcome page,
but when i am logging in from user to(admin) the error is coming

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other
>   types.

on `user = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` this line

here is my code

```
    public class loginuser
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        public string role { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool getlogintype(string role, string username, string password)
        {

            string tru = "";
            string fals = "";
            bool user;
            string strname = "";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=erp.hti-india.com,1434;Initial Catalog=erp;Connect Timeout=3600;User Id=erprakesh;Password=14erprakesh14");
            List<object> login = new List<object>();
            if (role == "Admin" || role == "Super Admin" || role !=null)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [admin] where userid='" + username + "' and pass ='" + password + "'", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    user = true;
                    //HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"] = username.ToString();
                    //HttpContext.Current.Session["tru"] = tru.ToString();
                    // want to redirect to welcome page if condition satisfied.
                }
                else
                {
                    user = false;
                    //want to show the label error message(declare as string errormsg)
                }
                con.Close();
            }
con.Open();
            user = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `select * from` then using `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`?? Not sure what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I just want to validate username and password

Comment: @Ric should i user select statement like

`select userid,pass from admin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns `null`, represented by `DBNull.Value`. You should check on that before converting to a boolean:

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == DBNull.Value)
{
    user = false; // or something like that
}
else
{
    user = Convert.ToBoolean(result);
}
```

Be aware that your statement is vulnerable for SQL injection. Always use parameterized queries! Also be careful with your `select *`. If you add columns you might end up in problems. Only select the field you require.

Comment: how i return result, do i need to convert? i am facing an error

Comment: I need to return user

`return result;` I tried this 

`return Convert.ToBoolean(result);` and this